# Is there any way to abort an ipc async request sending in electron?

Tags: asynchronous, ecmascript-6, listener, ipc, electron

I wrote some code for sending an async request via ipc in electron, but I wanna know that how can I abort or cancel the ipc requests which I already sent out.

```
ipc.on('receivedSoftwareInfo', (info) => {
    // TO-DO
});

ipc.send('getSoftwareInfo');
```

I had searched the api documents from [Repo](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/ipc-main.md) of electron, and got an information that I can stop by invoking removeListener like following code so that events I bind won't trigger.

```
ipc.removeAllListeners();
```

But I think there is a potential problem if user click the button and request again immediately, it will remove all of listener by program's side, then ipc send request second time.

It will look like following flow:

```
Events are removed -> async request is still there -> bind events again -> trigger
(I don't want it happen and trigger by old request)
```

So, is there any way to abort an ipc async request sending in electron? I think it's better than removing all of listeners to solve this question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunaly, that is not possible. An IPC request is managed by the browser (here, Electron) and cannot be managed in JavaScript.